# infinite loop in vuejs methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to select a component and unselect, for which I have the following function but it looks like the method is entering both if and if-else, I have tried various combination of if and if-else but still it's same. Should I use vuex to set the data?

```
 getRowClass({ id, Status }) {
  let rowClass = "list-row";

  if (this.selectedId === id) {
    if (this.selectedId != this.alreadyClicked) {
      rowClass += " list-row--selected";
      this.alreadyClicked = id;
      alert("alreadyClicked "+this.alreadyClicked)
    } else if (this.alreadyClicked!=0) {
      rowClass += " list-row";
      this.alreadyClicked = 0;
      alert("alreadyCli "+this.alreadyClicked)

    }
  }

  if (Status == "Ready") {
    rowClass += " list-row--online";
  } else {
    rowClass += " list-row--offline";
  }

  return rowClass;
},
```

Comment: If you're using this method in your template, I'd recommend moving it to a computed property instead. Methods should not be used in your HTML other than for event handlers

Comment: yes you are right but after making suggested change, error: Unexpected side effect in "getRowClass" computed property

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the unSelectedId variable to Vuex to the central state management

```
methods: {
  ...mapActions("stations", [
    "selectAux",
    "unSelectAux",
  ]),
  togglePageMode(id) {
    this.unSelectAux(id); // add unset id to vuex via this function 

  }
}


compute:{
getRowClass({...}){
   if (this.unSelectedId === id && this.selectedId == 0) {
            rowClass += " list-row";
          } else if (this.selectedId != 0 && this.selectedId === id) {
            rowClass += " list-row--selected";
          }
}
}
```